# Android: AlertDialog inside another AlertDialog's listener

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

UPDATE: Something must've been wrong with Eclipse, since I didn't get any logged errors on the crash. I not get this error when the app crashes as described:

```
The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's 
parent first.
```

This occurs when running the noteview.show() method the second time.

---

### Original post

I have a problem with an `AlertDialog`, which is started from inside the listener of another `AlertDialog`.

Here's the code for creating the dialogs and the listener and `show()` of the dialog(s):

```
AlertDialog.Builder mdialog;
ArrayAdapter<String> popmenu;
EditText input;

mdialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(ShoppingListApp03Activity.this);
popmenu  = new ArrayAdapter<String>(ShoppingListApp03Activity.this,
           android.R.layout.select_dialog_item);
popmenu.add("Notes");
popmenu.add("Remove");
noteview = new AlertDialog.Builder(ShoppingListApp03Activity.this)
noteview.setTitle("Notes");
input = new EditText(this);
noteview.setView(input);

lv.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {
   @Override
       public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                                                     long id) {
           final String sitem = items.get(position).getId();
           mdialog.setAdapter(popmenu, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
              @Override
              public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                 if (item == 0) {
                    updateFooter("Not implemented. (" + sitem + ")");
                noteview.show();
                 } else {
                    deleteitem = Integer.parseInt(sitem);
                    rmvdialog.show();
                 }
              }
           });

           mdialog.show();
           return false;
        }
     });

/* Click listener for the "Notes" popup menu: */
noteview.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
        Editable value = input.getText();
        // Do something with value!
    }
});
noteview.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
        // Canceled.
    }
});
```

The `onItemLongClickListener` opens a popup menu which presents two choices.

The second, which starts `rmvdialog()`, does its job well. No problems there.

The first, which opens the notes dialog, has a problem: On the first access, it opens the notes dialog and presents the message and the `OK` and `Cancel` buttons. However, after returning to the list (main view), either by clicking `OK` or `Cancel` in the notes dialog (since neither does anything yet), a second long click and selection of the notes dialog crashes the application.

The crash is without error logging. A `try-catch` around `noteview.show()` doesn't reveal anything either.

I am going blind looking at my own code, so there's probably something rotten in the design, but I can't see what.

The overall functionality here is a list with several items. When long-clicking on one of the items, a popup menu with two entries shows. Then, when long-clicking on the one called "notes", a dialog for showing/editing text, for the item in the list, is presented.

Comment: You never dismiss a dialog so your second show might result in the described crash. Have you tried to uncouple the (sorry) messy code to make it cleaner?

Comment: Any hints on how to do that (make it cleaner)? I find it hard to write very tidy code when using inline classes and listeners like that...

I get the not dismissing the dialog part. But where/how should I dismiss it? In the listener?

Comment: BTW: I tried cancelling the dialog in the listener, by adding "dialog.cancel()" on clicking the cancel button. This didn't change anything - the app still crashes (or an exception is thrown) the second time I open the dialog and click cancel.

Comment: If you have an exception, paste it. Cancel doesn't dismiss it from the view stack afaik. So you should really call dismiss instead of cancel.

Comment: noteview.cancel() or noteview.dismiss() does absolutely nothing. I can open the dialog once, but when I try to open it a second time the exception is caught: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.

Comment: I just cannot figure out how/where to call the removeView().

Comment: Please provide the code of a sample activity which uses your two dialogs. The current code snippet rely on too many not known variables so I am not able to test it. Also next time please paste the stack trace into the question, not into a comment.

Comment: Sorry about that. I've updated the post with the code for the main Activity. Thanks for you help/advice/hints/tips.

Comment: Your code is not testable as you still use variables and layout and ids you don't provide. Please create a test activity that contains all necessary stuff.

Comment: Sorry, then. There's no way to upload all the files/the whole project, and typing a handful of files into a post here is a bit overboard.

Comment: I found the culprit, though. It's this line: notedialog.setView(input); Apparently, I need to remove the view from the note dialog, but I'm not sure why.

Comment: It's not possible to remove an EditText from an AlertView, like it is f.ex. possible to remove a ListView from its parent with ((ListView)lv.getParent()).removeView(lv);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you too just found out the same I did. Here is my test activity which I requested from you. As you can see it is a stripped down version of yours (except I use onclick instead of onlongclick)

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private Builder firstDialogBuilder;
    private AlertDialog firstDialog;
    private Builder secondDialogBuilder;
    private AlertDialog secondDialog;
    private ListView secondListView;
    private ListView firstListView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        firstDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        firstListView = new ListView(this);
        firstListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, new String[] {"First Item1", "First Item2"}));
        firstDialogBuilder.setView(firstListView);
        firstListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                secondListView = new ListView(MainActivity.this);
                secondListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, new String[] {"Second Item1", "Second Item2"}));
                secondDialogBuilder.setView(secondListView);
                secondDialog = secondDialogBuilder.create();
                secondDialog.show();
            }
        });

        secondDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        secondListView = new ListView(this);
        secondListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, new String[] {"Second Item1", "Second Item2"}));
        secondDialogBuilder.setView(secondListView);

        secondDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("ok", new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ok on second", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                secondDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        secondDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("cancel", new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "cancel on second", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                secondDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        firstDialog = firstDialogBuilder.create();
        firstDialog.show();
    }
}
```

For the next time, please provide something like that to help us helping you :)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Yeah, sorry - I was just sitting here trying to make time for rewriting the Activity without all the other objects and stuff. I'll do that up-front next time. So, to conclude: The problem was that I only made the AlertDialogBuilder, instead of first creating the Builder and then the AlertDialog out of that. And, I also noticed that I HAVE to create the AlertDialog from the Builder inside the on(Long)Click method, like you're doing here. If I create it ousite, the buttons and listener won't be added.